# Changing the language of a filechooser java

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filechooser

I'm doing a program that requests that I change the names on the labels of my filechooser in java
I have tried multiple ways with no results.
I want to switch the language to spanish that's why I can't use Locale

Found this code online but don't know how to implement it:
UIManager.put("FileChooser.openDialogTitleText","your text here");
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(rootComponent);

Comment: What was the problem with `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("es", "..."));`?

Comment: I have tried that but don't know why it's not working as intended, what should you put in the "..."?

Comment: The country, like "ES".

Comment: There are many properties in UIManage, like "Cancel". Not really familiar with myself.

Comment: I have added Locale.setDefault(new Locale("es","ES"); but it still doesn't work, should i put it before or after the initComponents()?

Comment: Before. Not entirely confident it works. There are also SPANISH constants probably.

Comment: In every case the file chooser can be severely customized, butons and such.

Comment: @Mat2002 how did you fix it?

Comment: _Fixed it!_ I see that you have the [informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed?userid=19445204) badge which means you read the [tour] page and therefore you read this: _With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming._ Other people may be trying, unsuccessfully, to do what you have succeeded in doing and so may benefit from your "fix". You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).